# Insert missing rows in a dataframe based in values criteria

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Given a dataframe like this

```
country      rest         count
Argentina    pizza        26
Argentina    asador       22
Brazil       feijoada     52
Brazil       pizza        67
Germany      pizza        22
Germany      biergarten   52
Germany      kebab        20
```

Let's suppose we want all the unique values in 'rest' column to be represented in as many rows as countries in the dataframe, even if they have no values. My desired output would look like this:

```
country      rest         count
Argentina    pizza        26
Argentina    asador       22
Argentina    feijoada     0
Argentina    biergarten   0
Argentina    kebab        0
Brazil       pizza        67
Brazil       feijoada     52
Brazil       asador       0
Brazil       biergarten   0
Brazil       kebab        0
Germany      pizza        22
Germany      biergarten   52
Germany      kebab        20
Germany      asador       0
Germany      feijoada     0
```

Is there any simple way to reach this output through dplyr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
tidyr::complete(dat, country, rest, fill=list(count=0))
# # A tibble: 15 x 3
#    country   rest       count
#    <chr>     <chr>      <dbl>
#  1 Argentina asador        22
#  2 Argentina biergarten     0
#  3 Argentina feijoada       0
#  4 Argentina kebab          0
#  5 Argentina pizza         26
#  6 Brazil    asador         0
#  7 Brazil    biergarten     0
#  8 Brazil    feijoada      52
#  9 Brazil    kebab          0
# 10 Brazil    pizza         67
# 11 Germany   asador         0
# 12 Germany   biergarten    52
# 13 Germany   feijoada       0
# 14 Germany   kebab         20
# 15 Germany   pizza         22
```